# Code for Discord.js responding with a throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I created a simple logging bot that will log a server to a specific logging server, soon I'll make it a simple and easy to use bot for everyone to use, but I came across a problem.

the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const KeepAlive = require('./server');

client.on('ready', async ()=> {
    console.log('Connected as '+client.user.tag)
});

client.on('message', function (msg) {
    const Logged = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(msg.author.tag)
        .addField('userID -', msg.author.id)
        .addField('Channel -', msg.channel)
        .addField('Message -', msg.content)
        .setColor('0x00AAFF')
        .setTimestamp();

    if (msg.author.tag === 'CLIENT ID GOES HERE') {
        console.log('')
    } else if (msg.author.username) {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID GOES HERE')
        channel.send(Logged)
    }
});

client.on('messageDelete', msg => {
    const DLogged = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(msg.author)
        .addField('Channel -', msg.channel)
        .addField('Message -', msg.content)
        .setColor('#ff221a')
        .setTimestamp();

    if (msg.author.id === 'CLIENT ID GOES HERE') {
        console.log('')
    } else if (msg.author.username) {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID GOES HERE')
        channel.send(DLogged)
    }
});

KeepAlive()
client.login(process.env.token);
```

the error:

```
sageEmbed.js:432
    if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
                ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
```

but the error for me wasn't as simple as I thought, it says something about an embed so I tried to simplify it and it never worked as in a simple description with the message. That never worked for me though. I had no choice but to post on stackoverflow so hopefully the community can help me out, it'll be much appreciated!

Comment: It might be `.addField('Channel -', msg.channel)`. `msg.channel` is an object, and may be why you are getting this error. Try `msg.channel.id` instead?

Comment: I still get the same error the `.addField('Channel -', msg.channel)` will get `@general` but the `msg.channel.id` gets the id for example `192856294756294759`. the fields are correct as far as I know of. Other than that, I believe I correctly displayed everything correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be caused by messages with no text content (embed/image upload, etc)

When a message is sent with no text content, `msg.content` will be set to `""`.

As a result, the field's value is then an empty string and throws the error.

To fix this, add a check for the content:

```js
// for example
client.on('message', function (msg) {
    const Logged = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(msg.author.tag)
        .addField('userID -', msg.author.id)
        .addField('Channel -', msg.channel)
        // check for empty content
        .addField('Message -', msg.content === "" ? "no content" : msg.content)
        .setColor('0x00AAFF')
        .setTimestamp();

    if (msg.author.tag === 'CLIENT ID GOES HERE') {
        console.log('')
    } else if (msg.author.username) {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID GOES HERE')
        channel.send(Logged)
    }
});
```

Comment: @Watz You could also replace `msg.content === "" ? "no content" : msg.content` by a simple `msg.content || "no content"`. Also, if it solved your problem, don't forget to accept @theusaf's answer by clicking the checkmark (✓).